# Train model externally via API

Tags: google-cloud-ml

We have successfully deployed our prediction model and was able to call predictions for our applications. However, we would like to continuously train the model as we use it on our applications. This would be sending one set of data everytime a user sees that the prediction is wrong. I've checked the docs and only found about the API that creates a job.

Is there a way to send training data externally via API to GCP-ML? If so, please provide the docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I've understood about your question, the functionality you are looking for is something to the effect of:

- There is some process (e.g. streaming pipeline) with access to labeled data
- Said process sends instances out for prediction
- Process compares predictions from model to known label
- Labeled data is used to update the model
- Updated model becomes available for prediction

Google's CloudML Engine does not currently support this as a first class use case.

In our experience, a safer model for production environments (especially business critical processes) does not automatically update a model in production without prior evaluation. So a common paradigm is:

- Wait for some new data to come in (e.g. 1 day worth of logs, or even just a few hours or few minutes worth of new data)
- Update a copy of the model with the new data
- Evaluate the updated model to ensure it is better
- If so, push the model to production as a new version (in order to easily revert to the old version) and use a staged rollout to gradually direct new traffic to the new version.

For more information, you might be interested in [this KDD paper on TFX](http://www.kdd.org/kdd2017/papers/view/tfx-a-tensorflow-based-production-scale-machine-learning-platform), which is not yet available as a service or open source.